# Replacing letters with numbers in python objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

I am trying to replace all letters of a python object with numbers, in a Pandas DataFrame.

Example: I have a column of 3000 course codes, ex. A0101P. I am trying to replace all the letters of the alphabet in the course code with corresponding numbers (A =1, B=2 etc) so the output looks like this "1010116" (and most importantly, is an integer not an object/string)

The course code was initially a python object. So I have used

```py
course.to_string()
```

to change it to string value.

Then, I have created a mapping and then used str.replace to replace the values.

```py
mapping = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4, "E": 5, "F": 6, "G": 7, "H": 8, "I": 9, "J": 10, "K": 11, "L": 12, "M": 13, "N": 14, "O": 15, "P": 16, "Q":17,"R":18, "S": 19, "T": 20,"U": 21, "V": 22, "W": 23, "X": 24, "Y": 25, "Z":26}

courseDone = course.str.replace(course["Cursus code"], mapping)
```

It raises an error

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I have also tried

```py
for key, value in mapping.items():
    course = course.replace(key, value)
```

and it raises error

```py
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int
```

Even though the datatype is a string.

Example data:

```py
1       A0101P
2       A0111P
3       A0200P
4       A0201P
5       A0202P
```

Desired output:

```py
1       1010116
2       1011116
3       1020016
4       1020116
5       1020216
```

I have also tried to change the datatype with str() and the end errors are the same.

When I use

```py
for key, value in mapping.items():
    course["Cursus code"] = course["Cursus code"].replace(key, value)
```

I receive no error, but the output remains the same.

I am new to python and I have tried my best to find a solution but nothing seems to work.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: use `course.replace(course["Cursus code"], mapping)` instead. And put str values in your mapping: `{"A": "1", "B": "2", "C": "3", "D": "4", ...}` and finally convert result to `int`

Comment: "The course code was initially a python object. So I have used course.to_string() to change it to string value." Strings are object in Python. Do you mean `course` is a `pandas.Dataframe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly solution is to replace the letters one by one, similar to yours, but have to map numbers to string:

```
for k,v in mapping.items():
    v = str(v)
    course["Cursus code"] = course["Cursus code"].str.replace(k,v)
```

Output:

```
0    1010116
1    1011116
2    1020016
3    1020116
4    1020216
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I chose this answer as it was the most understandable for me and it actually worked. Other answers theoretically should have worked but did not for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

strings are kept as 'objects' in pandas. You can use info() method of a dataframe to see which columns are integer, objects (for strings), timestampts, etc like:

```
df.info()
```

As to your question, you can use apply method and replace your string with desired mapping, like that:

```
def str_to_int_map(string, mapping):

   return int(''.join([str(mapping.get(x, x)) for x in string]))
mapping = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4, "E": 5, "F": 6, "G": 7, "H": 8, "I": 9, "J": 10, "K": 11, "L": 12, "M": 13, "N": 14, "O": 15, "P": 16, "Q":17,"R":18, "S": 19, "T": 20,"U": 21, "V": 22, "W": 23, "X": 24, "Y": 25, "Z":26}
df['Course'] = df['Course'].apply(lambda x: str_to_int_map(x, mapping))
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I have actually used df.info() on my initial df and the datatype was object. Then, I have used the to_string(), and when checked with .info() again I received an error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'info', hence I have assumed it's a completely different type.

Comment: .info would work for for pandas dataframe objects. info() because it's a built-in method for pandas dataframe objects. you can't use this method for string objects

Answer (score 0):

you can use map aswell to replace values with a dict, it's pretty clean.
Then about your string issue, is it because you didn't allocate your result?

like :
`course = course.to_string()
courseDone = course.str.replace(course["Cursus code"], mapping)`

or

`courseDone = course.to_string().str.replace(course["Cursus code"], mapping)`

Answer (score 0):

The below example is like your current structure. But there are lots of ways to do this. Expand the mapping as you see fit. And also note that iterating through a dict is different in Python 2/3. Notice that both the key and value are strings in the dict.

```
string_to_change = 'abc123'
mapping_dict = dict(zip(['a','b','c'],['1','2','3']))
for k, v in mapping_dict.iteritems():
    string_to_change = string_to_change.replace(k,v)
'''
```